# Converting local date-times from a large dataset with multiple time zones into UTC

Tags: r, timezone, utc

I have been given a massive data set that contains latitude, longitude, local date and local time fields. I'm trying to organize this information into an ISO UTC time field. I'm having a problem with my code because I don't know how to use as.POSIXct() when multiple time zones are in the data. Whenever I try to use an array or loop in the tz = portion, I receive an error.

I've used the tz_lookup_coords() function from the lutz package to define the time zone of each row in the data frame. I have also been able to filter my data to a single time zone and successfully used the as.POSIXct() and format() functions to get the UTC time. However, I would like a more elegant solution to apply a single code to the entire dataset.

```
sample<- data.frame(
  "localDate" = c("2015-04-20","2016-07-17","2015-08-06"), 
  "localTime" = c("14:00", "14:46", NA ), 
  "timeZone" = c("Pacific/Pago_Pago", NA , "Pacific/Honolulu")
)

# Change times from local to UTC
sample$localDateTime <- paste(sample$localDate, sample$localTime, sep = " ")
for (i in 1:nrow(sample)) {
  sample[i,]$localDateTime <- as.POSIXct(sample[i,]$localDateTime, tz= sample[i,]$timeZone, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
}
sample$eventDate <- format(sample$localDateTime, tz= "UTC", usetz = TRUE)
```

When I enter a single time zone like "Pacific/Honolulu" the code works great, but it will treat each row as if it is in one time zone.

```
> sample
   localDate localTime          timeZone    localDateTime               eventDate
1 2015-04-20     14:00 Pacific/Pago_Pago 2015-04-20 14:00 2015-04-21 00:00:00 UTC
2 2016-07-17     14:46    Pacific/Saipan 2016-07-17 14:46 2016-07-18 00:46:00 UTC
3 2015-08-06     10:35  Pacific/Honolulu 2015-08-06 10:35 2015-08-06 20:35:00 UTC
```

If I try to use anything besides a character string in quotes for the tz = portion of the function, I receive this code:

```
Error in strptime(x, format, tz = tz) : invalid 'tz' value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the `timeZone` column being a factor instead of a character vector, use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when defining the data.frame to specify `timeZone` as a character column. You can also avoid any loops by using vectorized functions from the `lubridate` package:

```r
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(
    "localDate" = c("2015-04-20","2016-07-17","2015-08-06"), 
    "localTime" = c("14:00", "14:46", "10:35"), 
    "timeZone" = c("Pacific/Pago_Pago", "Pacific/Saipan", "Pacific/Honolulu"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df$eventDate <- force_tzs(ymd_hm(with(df, paste(localDate, localTime))), tzones = df$timeZone)

df
#>    localDate localTime          timeZone           eventDate
#> 1 2015-04-20     14:00 Pacific/Pago_Pago 2015-04-21 01:00:00
#> 2 2016-07-17     14:46    Pacific/Saipan 2016-07-17 04:46:00
#> 3 2015-08-06     10:35  Pacific/Honolulu 2015-08-06 20:35:00
```

---

Edit: in case of missing values, check for each row whether it can be converted and if not return `NA`. Below an example solution using base R:

```r
df <- data.frame(
    "localDate" = c("2015-04-20","2016-07-17","2015-08-06", "2019-01-01", "2019-01-01"), 
    "localTime" = c("14:00", "14:46", "10:35", NA, "00:00"), 
    "timeZone" = c("Pacific/Pago_Pago", "Pacific/Saipan", "Pacific/Honolulu", 
        "Pacific/Honolulu", NA),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df$eventDate <- apply(df, 1, function(row) {     
      ifelse(any(is.na(row)), NA_character_,
          format(as.POSIXct(paste(row["localDate"], row["localTime"]), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",
              tz = row["timeZone"]), tz = "UTC", usetz = TRUE)
      )
    })
df   
#>    localDate localTime          timeZone               eventDate
#> 1 2015-04-20     14:00 Pacific/Pago_Pago 2015-04-21 01:00:00 UTC
#> 2 2016-07-17     14:46    Pacific/Saipan 2016-07-17 04:46:00 UTC
#> 3 2015-08-06     10:35  Pacific/Honolulu 2015-08-06 20:35:00 UTC
#> 4 2019-01-01      <NA>  Pacific/Honolulu                    <NA>
#> 5 2019-01-01     00:00              <NA>                    <NA>
```

Comment: lubridate looks like it does exactly what I want, but when I tried to incorporate it into my code, I received the following error:
Error in C_force_tzs(as.POSIXct(time), tzones, tzone_out, roll) : 
  CCTZ: Unrecognized timezone: "NA"
In addition: Warning message:
 636621 failed to parse. 

I think the problem is that not all the data contain the necessary information such as timeZone or localTime

Comment: @SarahBingo You can edit your question to include data rows with such missing values

Comment: Better include it by adding an additional row with missing values in your defined data.frame. How would NA timezones or times be handled?

Comment: I guess I will have to find a way to filter out the rows with missing localTime and/or timeZone to use the force_tzs() function.  However, these are not my data to filter/manipulate. I wanted to keep all rows present and provide the UTC time for the rows that contain all necessary fields. The UTC time field would be left NA for rows with missing information.

Comment: @SarahBingo I edited the response to include `NA`s in the data.frame. The solution uses only base R, but the same can be done with `lubridate`.

Comment: Your function(row) clause helped solve my dilemma. Thank you, @Joris Chau.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(lubridate)

sample <- 
  data.frame(
     "localDate" = c("2015-04-20","2016-07-17","2015-08-06"), 
     "localTime" = c("14:00", "14:46", "10:35"), 
     "timeZone" = c("Pacific/Pago_Pago", "Pacific/Saipan", "Pacific/Honolulu")
   )

sample$localDateTime <- 
  paste(sample$localDate, sample$localTime, sep = " ")

list <- 
  list()

for (i in 1:nrow(sample)){
     list[[i]] <- 
       ymd_hm(sample$localDateTime[i], 
              tz = as.character(sample$timeZone[i]))
   }

list   

R> list
[[1]]
[1] "2015-04-20 14:00:00 SST"

[[2]]
[1] "2016-07-17 14:46:00 ChST"

[[3]]
[1] "2015-08-06 10:35:00 HST"
```